# Creating a list data structure out of a data frame with sequenced column headers

Tags: r, data-structures, split

I recently started collecting a bunch of survey data using doForms (a derivative of ODK) and upon loading my data into R I realized I have to reshape it completely. Because in my survey I have a loop that of 9 questions that are all structured observation the column names are sequential.

For Ex.

```
  colnames(MasterDataframe)
  [1] "Date_Created"        "WaterType"           "Unique_barcode"      "VolumeStart.1."     
  [5] "StartTime.1."        "StopTime.1."         "VolumeEnd.1."        "UserType.1."        
  [9] "NYoungChildren.1."   "NChildren.1."        "NAdults.1."          "EventType.1."       
 [13] "VolumeStart.2."      "StartTime.2."        "StopTime.2."         "VolumeEnd.2."       
 [17] "UserType.2."         "NYoungChildren.2."   "NChildren.2."        "NAdults.2."         
 [21] "EventType.2."        "VolumeStart.3."      "StartTime.3."        "StopTime.3."        
 [25] "VolumeEnd.3."        "UserType.3."         "NYoungChildren.3."   "NChildren.3."       
 [29] "NAdults.3."
```

This goes on for quite some time. But you can see the pattern here.

I am trying to understand how I can extract the looping data and first put it into it's own data.frame for 1 row of the original data frame. So for example because I have 9 questions in a loop and lets say I have 20 loops (180 column headers in the MasterDataFrame) I need to condense this down to a data frame with 9 variables and 20 observations.

The caveat here is that any row of the masterdataframe contains a variable amount of loops.

I am unsure how to approach this problem. Any step in the right direction would help.

Because I load in this dataframe through a google doc you can look at it your self.

```
    require(RCurl)        
    myCsv <- getURL('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AhVuJMYFyexYdEpKWkFMby1QMXJhOVVXVXVtekFlbkE&single=true&gid=1&output=csv', cainfo='cacert.pem')
  MasterDataFrame<- (read.csv(textConnection(myCsv),stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

Edit: I figured this would spawn some negative review do to my lack of "showing work", but any direction is very appreciated. I am unsure what the the correct question to ask is and I couldn't find much if anything on the concept of "looped" column data.

Comment: You can use `reshape` for getting long data.

Comment: I am assuming what I have created is known as "wide formatted data". I have used the melt function before, but in a different context.

Comment: I am referring to `reshape` from base R . Have you tried `reshape`? I think you also need to use regular expression here. Would it be okay for you to post the sample data?

Comment: Ah! No I have not. Let me give that a go. I will repost my results

Comment: Have a look at the answers. But, it is not clear what are the unique identifiers in the data

Comment: Yes I should have been more clear about what the unique identifiers are. Thank you for the tip! This was extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mydf is your dataframe. You can use `Reshape` from splitstackshape package for this.

```
library(splitstackshape)
```

I asssume `c("Date_Created","WaterType","SS_TippyTap_barcode")` as unique identifiers

```
kk<-Reshape(mydf, id.vars=c("Date_Created","WaterType","SS_TippyTap_barcode"),
        var.stubs = c("VolumeStart", "StartTime", "StopTime","VolumeEnd","UserType","NYoungChildren","NChildren","NAdults","EventType"))
head(kk)
                Date_Created WaterType     SS_TippyTap_barcode                                Form_Record              Mobile_Device Edited_By
1 09/27/2013 15:56:38 GMT+02      Soap  TIPPYTAP_MAC_ID 63EA69 mannaenergy$$09252013072024$$Published&&15 *********/358304046130922        NA
2 09/27/2013 15:36:49 GMT+02     Water  TIPPYTAP_MAC_ID 8DA410 mannaenergy$$09252013072024$$Published&&14 *********/356525042608998        NA
3 09/27/2013 14:55:16 GMT+02      Soap TIPPYTAP_MAC_ID  63F096 mannaenergy$$09252013072024$$Published&&13 *********/358304046208553        NA
4 09/27/2013 14:43:59 GMT+02     Water  TIPPYTAP_MAC_ID 63EB1F mannaenergy$$09252013072024$$Published&&12 *********/358304046206888        NA
5 09/27/2013 14:34:24 GMT+02      Soap  TIPPYTAP_MAC_ID 63EA69 mannaenergy$$09252013072024$$Published&&10 *********/358304046130922        NA
6 09/27/2013 14:16:00 GMT+02      Soap TIPPYTAP_MAC_ID  63F096 mannaenergy$$09252013072024$$Published&&11 *********/358304046208553        NA
  Edit_Date time VolumeStart       StartTime        StopTime VolumeEnd       UserType NYoungChildren NChildren NAdults EventType
1        NA    1        1.70 09:04:41 GMT+02 09:05:19 GMT+02      1.60          Adult             NA        NA       1 DrawWater
2        NA    1        2.31 08:51:22 GMT+02 08:51:54 GMT+02      2.20          Adult             NA        NA       2 DrawWater
3        NA    1        2.30 10:03:48 GMT+02 10:03:51 GMT+02      2.25          Adult             NA        NA       1 DrawWater
4        NA    1        2.20 09:04:55 GMT+02 09:05:49 GMT+02      2.05 Under_5\nAdult              1        NA       1 DrawWater
5        NA    1        1.70 09:04:41 GMT+02 09:05:19 GMT+02      1.60          Adult             NA        NA       1 DrawWater
6        NA    1        2.30 10:03:48 GMT+02 10:03:51 GMT+02      2.25          Adult             NA        NA       1 DrawWater
```

Comment: WOW! This is a different way to approach this problem than I had considered. At first I wasn't quite sure what you had done, but this is really great! I can easily subset this data frame using this restructuring! Your assumptions were spot on by the way! If I may ask how does the argument var.stubs work?

Comment: I am also using this package for the first time. I think `Reshape` uses regular expression to match the 9 vars specified in the var.stubs by looking into all other colnames which have identical names as element of var.stubs but are different only with respect to the characters appearing after `.` (this is called as `sep`) default).

Answer (score 0):

```
longfrm <- rbind( dfrm[, c(1:3, grep("\\.1$", names(dfrm)), 184:187)] ,
       dfrm[, c(1:3, grep("\\.2$", names(dfrm)), 184:187)] ,
       dfrm[, c(1:3, grep("\\.3$", names(dfrm)), 184:187)] )
longfrm$Times <- rep(1:3, each=nrow(dfrm))
```

After looking at the magnitude of the problem I see that you have trailing columns that need to be included and 20 repetitions, so may want to construct a loop.